# Can I make Windows behave like an ethernet hub?

Tags: windows, networking, bridge

I have two machines **A** and **C** mutually connected to NICs on a third machine, **B**, as follows: **A-B-C**

**B** is a Windows 7 machine configured with a bridge containing the **A-B** and **B-C** NICs, so that **A** and **C** can communicate. So far, so good.

I need frames from **A** destined for **B** to also arrive at **C**. Essentially, I would like Windows to behave like a hub rather than a switch. Is there any way to do this?

If you have any ideas at all, no matter how hacky or roundabout, I would love to hear from you! I have been tearing my hair out over this and by now I am willing to try anything. My only limitations are that I can't touch **A** or change to a different operating system on **B**.

Comment: Why don't you just buy a HUB....they are extremely cheap?

Comment: Machine **C** is a VM on **B**.

Comment: @dromedary What virtualization software?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the VM to share the physical adapter with the host rather than using a virtual adapter and bridging?

Comment: HyperV (Windows Hypervisor) only allows for a "virtual switch", not a "hub".  (you don't state which Virtual Server you are using).  I think your VM would need to somehow override this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to **bridge** your network.

I have never done this with windows, but I  if I go to 'network and sharing center' and right click on a network adaptop it shows a tab 'bridge connection'.

Comment: I am already bridging the network. I have tried to be very clear about what I want in my question: I am trying to get hub-like behaviour.

Comment: My excuses. I read your original question twice and still somehow miss interpreted it.   I guess extra hardware is not an option? (e.g. mirroring a port via a managed switch?)